# Merge (or create synonym) [structured-streaming] into [spark-structured-streaming]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Both tags refer to the same concept and a subset of questions is already double tagged.

- [[structured-streaming]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/structured-streaming/info) (created 2017-02-13) has 468 questions and 40 watchers.

  *Tag Info*:

  > Structured Streaming is a new stream processing model and engine built on Spark SQL since Apache Spark 2.0.0. It provides fast, scalable, fault-tolerant, end-to-end exactly-once stream processing with the Dataset/DataFrame APIs available in Scala, Java and Python.

  *Wiki*:

  Missing.
- [[spark-structured-streaming]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spark-structured-streaming/info) (created 2018-01-30) has 199 questions and 27 watchers.

  *Tag Info*:

  > Spark Structured Streaming allows processing live data streams using the Spark SQL engine. For programmers, this means that one can use the DataFrame API rather than the RDD API.
- 44 questions have both tags.

The former one is more popular, but the latter one is more specific, and closer to Spark tag conventions, where specific tags use `spark-` or `apache-spark-` prefix. Using prefixed version can also prevent some confusion in the future, if other "structured streaming" project becomes popular.

Merging tags would be prefer, but synonym should work too.

Comment: I just saw aobut four of these in a row on the Suggested Edit queue on the main site. Is this a thing? Are we doing this?